# show Error msg when text reach max length angular js \

Tags: angularjs, max, message

I have a **text field** on which i have used **max** checked of **angular js**.
its working absolutely fine but i want to show error in span if text.length reached the max length. like ng-if searchtext.length== max show a message

Answer (score 1):

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input
    type="text"
    name="myText"
    ng-model="myModel"
    ng-maxlength="2">
  <span ng-show="myForm.myText.$error.maxlength">Error</span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

using the Angular documentation : maxlength
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMaxlength

Example should be fine for you I hope